# It may not be negative and must be smaller than the size of the crowd

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I'm having a problem atm with this code and i wounder if anyone would mind helping me. I dont realy know why i get the error so would be awesome if some one could tell me why it happens.

I get the following error:

> Index was out of range. It may not be negative and must be smaller than the size of the crowd.

**Edit**: sry forgot to mark what is the problem :P

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace WindowsGame2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        private Rectangle Bounds = Rectangle.Empty;
        SpriteFont font;

        Texture2D gfx_shot;
        Texture2D gfx;
        Texture2D gfx_acc;
        Texture2D gfx_meteor;

        Vector2 position;
        Vector2 ship_speed = new Vector2();
        List<Vector2> shot_pos = new List<Vector2>();
        List<Vector2> shot_speed = new List<Vector2>();        
        List<Vector2> meteor_pos = new List<Vector2>();
        List<Vector2> meteor_speed = new List<Vector2>();

        Random myRnd = new Random();

        float angle = 0;
        const float ship_acc = 0.1f;
        const float ship_max_speed = 4;
        const int shot_delay = 200;
        int shot_time;
        int score = 0;

        double shot_rad = 3.25, 
            meteor_rad = 33;

        bool accelerate;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            // Här läggs SpriteBatch till som gör att man kan använda dem som en texture
            gfx = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ship");
            gfx_acc = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ship_acc");
            gfx_shot = Content.Load<Texture2D>("shot");
            font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("myFont");

            // Positionen av rymdskäpet
            position = new Vector2(200, 200);

            gfx_meteor = Content.Load<Texture2D>("meteor");
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                meteor_pos.Add(new Vector2(myRnd.Next(800), myRnd.Next(600)));
                double tmp_angle = (myRnd.Next(1000) * Math.PI * 2) / 1000.0;
                double tmp_speed = 0.5 + 3.0 * (myRnd.Next(1000) / 1000.0);
                meteor_speed.Add(new Vector2((float)(tmp_speed * Math.Cos(tmp_angle)),
                    (float)(tmp_speed * Math.Sin(tmp_angle))));
            }

            if (i < 10)
            {
                meteor_pos.Add(new Vector2(myRnd.Next(800), myRnd.Next(600)));
                double tmp_angle = (myRnd.Next(1000) * Math.PI * 2) / 1000.0;
                double tmp_speed = 0.5 + 3.0 * (myRnd.Next(1000) / 1000.0);
                meteor_speed.Add(new Vector2((float)(tmp_speed * Math.Cos(tmp_angle)),
                    (float)(tmp_speed * Math.Sin(tmp_angle))));
                i++;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            // Denna funktion känner av snap trycken för att köra rymdskäppet
            KeyboardState ks = Keyboard.GetState();

            if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {
                angle -= 0.05f;
            }
            if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            {
                angle += 0.05f;
            }
            if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {
                accelerate = true;

                ship_speed.X += ship_acc * (float)Math.Cos(angle);
                ship_speed.Y += ship_acc * (float)Math.Sin(angle);
                if (ship_speed.Length() > ship_max_speed)
                {
                    ship_speed.Normalize();
                    ship_speed *= ship_max_speed;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                accelerate = false;
            }

            position += ship_speed;

            // Detta kollar om rymdskäpet åker utanför skärmen. Om den gör det ska den komma in på andra sidan
            if (position.X < -80)
            {
                position.X = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width + 80;
            }
            if (position.X > graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width + 80)
            {
                position.X = -80;
            }
            if (position.Y < -60)
            {
                position.Y = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height + 60;
            }
            if (position.Y > graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height + 60)
            {
                position.Y = -60;
            }

            // Här kollar den alla viktiga detaljer om hur skoten funkar
            shot_time -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
            if (shot_time < 0)
            {
                shot_time = 0;
            }

            if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && shot_time == 0)
            {
                shot_time = shot_delay;
                shot_pos.Add(new Vector2(position.X, position.Y));
                shot_speed.Add(new Vector2(5 * (float)Math.Cos(angle), 5 * (float)Math.Sin(angle)));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < shot_pos.Count; i++)
            {
                shot_pos[i] += shot_speed[i];
                if (shot_pos[i].X < -100 || shot_pos[i].X > graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width + 100
                   || shot_pos[i].Y < -100 || shot_pos[i].Y > graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height + 100)
                {
                    shot_pos.RemoveAt(i);
                    shot_speed.RemoveAt(i);
                    continue;
                }

            }

            // Här updaterar vi Metorernas location
            for (int i = 0; i < meteor_pos.Count; i++)
            {
                meteor_pos[i] += meteor_speed[i];
                Vector2 v = meteor_pos[i];
                //Utanför skärmen?
                if (v.X < -80)
                    v.X = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width + 80;
                if (v.X > graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width + 80)
                    v.X = -80;
                if (v.Y < -60)
                    v.Y = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height + 60;
                if (v.Y > graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height + 60)
                    v.Y = -60;
                if (v.X == position.X)
                    break;

                //Uppdatera i listan
                meteor_pos[i] = v;
            }

            for (int a = 0; a < meteor_pos.Count; a++)
            {

                double ship_xplus = position.X + meteor_pos[a].X;
                double ship_xminus = position.X - meteor_pos[a].X;
                double ship_yplus = position.Y + meteor_pos[a].Y;
                double ship_yminus = position.Y - meteor_pos[a].Y;


                if ((ship_xplus * ship_xplus + ship_yplus * ship_yplus) < (shot_rad + meteor_rad) * (shot_rad + meteor_rad))
                {

                }
                else if ((ship_xminus * ship_xminus + ship_yminus * ship_yminus) < (shot_rad + meteor_rad) * (shot_rad + meteor_rad))
                {

                }
            }

            // Test
            //Om det finns skott o meteoriter så kolla kollision
            if (shot_pos.Count > 0 && meteor_pos.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < shot_pos.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int a = 0; a < meteor_pos.Count; a++)
                    {
                        float xdiff = shot_pos[i].X - meteor_pos[a].X;
                        float ydiff = shot_pos[i].Y - meteor_pos[a].Y;


                        if ((xdiff * xdiff + ydiff * ydiff) < (shot_rad + meteor_rad) * (shot_rad + meteor_rad))
                        {
                            shot_pos.RemoveAt(i);
                            shot_speed.RemoveAt(i);
                            meteor_pos.RemoveAt(a);
                            meteor_speed.RemoveAt(a);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            // Starta renderingen av rymdskäppet
            spriteBatch.Begin();

                // Om rymdskäppet accelerar så kör denna renderings processen och lägg till eld bakom rymdskäpet
                if (accelerate)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(gfx_acc, position, null, Color.White, angle + (float)Math.PI / 2, new Vector2(gfx.Width / 2, gfx.Height / 2), 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
                }
                // Om rymdskäppet svänger kör denna renderings processen
                spriteBatch.Draw(gfx, position, null, Color.White, angle + (float)Math.PI / 2, new Vector2(gfx.Width / 2, gfx.Height / 2), 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);

                // Här skriver den hur många skot du har skjutit på skärmen
                for (int i = 0; i < shot_pos.Count; i++)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(gfx_shot, shot_pos[i], null, Color.White, 0, new Vector2(gfx_shot.Width / 2, gfx_shot.Height / 2), 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);

                }

                // Här gör vi en font som skriver hur många skot det är just nu på skärmen
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Shots: " + shot_pos.Count, new Vector2(10, 10), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Score: " + score, new Vector2(10, 35), Color.White);

                // Här gör vi så metorerna renderas utt på skärmen
                for (int i = 0; i < meteor_pos.Count; i++)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(gfx_meteor, meteor_pos[i], null, Color.White, 0,
                        new Vector2(gfx_meteor.Width / 2, gfx_meteor.Height / 2), 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
                }
            // Avsluta renderingen av rymdskäppet

                //if (Collision())
                    //spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "You were killed", new Vector2(10, 10), Color.White);

            spriteBatch.End();
        }
    }
}
```

The error is this:
**float xdiff = shot_pos[i].X - meteor_pos[a].X;**

Comment: *Way* too much code. Please at least point out which line its on.

Comment: Somewhere, in that huge blob of messy code, you're removing items from the collection you're iterating, messing up your indexes.

Comment: 1) [Break when the exception you are seeing is thrown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx).  2) Debug.

Comment: Ignore the answer I gave below, it fixes a bug where the element formerly at `i+1` in `shot_pos` will be skipped when removing an element at index `i` - but won't fix the exception.  There's not enough information in your post for us to know what is happening.  Either there's a bad check in the `meteor_pos` or `shot_pos` classes, or the `shot_speed` or `meteor_speed` lists do not have the sizes you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of it is what Peirre-Luc Pineault is saying. You are going through a loop, removing elements, and then STILL going through the loop. This sometimes causes out of bounds (very likely will). I'm actually surprised it lets you do that.

If you look at the Update(GameTime gametime) function you'll eventually see...

```
if (shot_pos.Count > 0 && meteor_pos.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < shot_pos.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < meteor_pos.Count; a++)
        {
            float xdiff = shot_pos[i].X - meteor_pos[a].X;
            float ydiff = shot_pos[i].Y - meteor_pos[a].Y;


            if ((xdiff * xdiff + ydiff * ydiff) < (shot_rad + meteor_rad) * (shot_rad + meteor_rad))
            {
                shot_pos.RemoveAt(i);
                shot_speed.RemoveAt(i);
                meteor_pos.RemoveAt(a);
                meteor_speed.RemoveAt(a);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think major issue is here:
Here you are cycling through 2 lists, but using those loop variables to remove elements from 4 different lists. You go through the list of "shot_pos" and "meteor_pos", but removing elements (based on index position) from "shot_pos" (which is ok), "meteor_pos" (which is ok), and then "shot_speed"+"meteor_speed" (whoooaaa nelly!).

While you can be pretty confident shot_pos and meteor_pos are in range, you do not know if shot_speed and meteor_speed are actually in range because you are not checking for it.

Solution: I think, without modifying the original code too much, simply doing a valid range check is ok.

Meaning:

```
shot_pos.RemoveAt(i);
if (i< shot_speed.Count){
    shot_speed.RemoveAt(i);
}
meteor_pos.RemoveAt(a);
if (a<meteor_speed.Count){
    meteor_speed.RemoveAt(a);
}
continue;
```

This issue, as I was getting at before, is that you have no way of confirming that this data lines up. So that shot_speed at i of 2 is meant for shot_pos at i of 2.

A more complex solution would be to combine data that goes together in a structure or class.

The MSDN tutorial for structures is actually decent: [here]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

But I always like the [this site the most]http://www.dotnetperls.com/struct

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a bit different approach when i need to remove bullets or meteors. On collision I set a flag to true. And then i remove them all together.

In basic pseudo code

```
for each m in meteors
    for each b in bullets
        if m.collide(b) {b.removeIt = true;}
    next
next
```

and then

```
bullet.removeAll(function(c) c.removeIt);
```